# Access download_url <a> attribute from

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to pull the MimeType and filename from a Chrome hyperlink, such as in GMail. I see the anchor tag looks like:

```
<a download_url="MIME-TYPE:FILENAME:https:..." href="https:...">Download</a>
```

I have registered for a context menu on links with something like:
    chrome.contextMenus.create({'contexts':['link']})

However, when I get the callback, the OnClickData only has a linkUrl, which is the href.

Is there any clever way I can access the "download_url" attribute for the link from my callback? Seems like a content script that finds the URL is the only way, and that feels like overkill.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome contextMenus API doesn't provide you that information.  It doesn't tell you what element was clicked.

I imagine you can code a workaround, capturing the right clicks events, in order to know the element clicked (event.target).  If you remember this element, you will use it to retrieve the property you desire when your contextMenu listener fires.